# Find the probability.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Suppose that an individual's initials consist of 3 letters of alphabet. Prove that in a large city there are at least two people with the same initials.

Comment: The title seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are $26^3$ many types of initials-people; if the city has more than that amount of inhabitants, at least two will fall within the same type. (pigeonhole principle, the tag says it all).